# How to avoid switch case in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am writing a CRUD for the JPA entity and I need to implement updating of fields. I have a list of updatable field names in array in every class. I ask the user to enter field name he wants to update and value he wants to update this attribute to. I validate if the entered field name is valid for the context of Entity and after that, I need to update some field based on attribute name. How can I avoid using switch case here?
code:

```java
package com.kindgeek.monitoring.service;

import com.kindgeek.monitoring.entity.Person;
import com.kindgeek.monitoring.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;

@Service
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        Iterable<Person> iterable = personRepository.findAll();
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        iterable.forEach(persons::add);
        return persons;
    }

    public Optional<Person> findById(Long id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Map<String, String> addPerson(Person person) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        };

        personRepository.save(person);
        return response;
    }
    public Map<String, String> updatePersonAttribute(String updateKey, String updateValue, Person person){
        switch (updateKey){
            case "": //Here I need to do updating
        }
    }
    public Map<String, String> updatePerson(HashMap<String, String> personUpdate, Long id) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        };

        Optional<Person> personOptional = personRepository.findById(id);
        if (personOptional.isPresent()) {
            Person person = personOptional.get();
            Set<String> updateKeys = personUpdate.keySet();
            for (String updateKey : updateKeys) {
                boolean keyValid = Arrays.asList(Person.modifiableAttributes).contains(updateKey);
                if (keyValid) {
                    String updateValue = personUpdate.get(updateKey);
                    HashMap<String, String> updateResponse = updatePersonAttribute(updateKey, updateValue, person);
                    response.putAll(updateResponse);

                }
            }
        } else {
            response.put("error", "true");
            response.put("errorText", String.format("Person with id %d is not found", id));
        }
        return response;
    }


    public Long count() {
        return personRepository.count();
    }

    public void deleteById(Long personId) {
        personRepository.deleteById(personId);
    }

}
```

P.S. I thought that I need something like Trigger classes, and methods with a signature like this `updateAttribute(NameTrigger trigger, String newName)`. But I don`t know is this a good approach and if it is, should I use manually written classes or not.

Comment: You can avoid them by not using them. delete it and replace it by a conditional statement

Comment: I understand, but it will be pretty much the same thing on the lower level.

Comment: You can create a global map of `Map<String, BiConsumer<Person, String>` wherein the key of the map is the `updateKey` and the value is a function that takes a `Person` and the new `updateValue`. You can fill this static map and just do a `map.get(updateKey).apply(person, updateValue)` then.

It can be filled as follows: `map.put("myKey", (person, value) -> person.setMyKey(value));`. You can make it non-static to access functions to do more complex processing.

Comment: then again, logically speaking, that somewhat does the same

Comment: Well its all about declaration vs. "actual code" and I like the declarative approach of a `Map` more (subjective ofc) although I would propose an enum as a key and an `EnumMap` for a super-fast lookup. Some pendantics will want test-coverage on `switch` which you don't need in the `Map` approach.

But yes, fundamentally speaking all kind of caseing is the same ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code example to accompany my comment of using a lookup `Map` to resolve an update function to use for a given `updateKey`:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

class Scratch62323277 {

    static class MyProcessor {
        private Map<String, BiConsumer<Person, String>> processors = new HashMap<>();

        {
            processors.put("name", this::setName);
            processors.put("lastName", this::setLastName);
        }

        public void update(String key, String value, Person person) {
            //TODO: maybe nullcheck the map-get
            processors.get(key).accept(person, value);
        }

        private void setName(Person person, String value) {
            person.setName(value);
        }

        private void setLastName(Person person, String value) {
            // ignore null values (as an example)
            if (value == null) {
                return;
            }
            person.setName(value);
        }
    }

    static class Person {
        private String name;
        private String lastName;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

I would advise you to use an enum for the keys and use an `EnumMap` as they have better performance characteristics compared to a `HashMap` (perfect hashing alike, no collisions etc. - it's basically just an indexed array access)

Comment: Can I make it not void?

Comment: `BiFunction<Person, String, Person>` :) (take a person and a string, return a person)